# Trying to make an encryption code but gets many errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, encryption, counter

```
alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"," ","."]
print(alphabet[0])
user_input = "this is a test."
user_sentance = list(user_input)

print(user_sentance)

#user_sentance = user_input.split()
#print(user_sentance)
counter = 0

#def remove_space():
 #   return string.replace(" ", "")

#def remove_period():
#    user_sentance.replace(".", "")

counter_1 = 0

def counter_2():
    counter_2 = 0   


def counter_1():
    counter_1 = 0   

def main():
    for i in user_sentance:
        counter_1 = 0
        counter_2 = 0
        for x in alphabet:

            if user_sentance[counter_1] == alphabet[counter_2]:
                print(counter_2)
                main()
                counter_2 = 0
            else:
                main()
                counter_2 += 1
        counter_1 += 1

        #if "." in user.sentance[counter]:
         #   user_sentance[counter].replace(".","")
          #  print(user_sentance)
           # main()
        #else:
        #    break


main()
```

This is what it is printing:

```
a

['t', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't', '.']
```

Then the errors start here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Shah family/Desktop/Coding/python/encrypted code.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/Users/Shah family/Desktop/Coding/python/encrypted code.py", line 40, in main
    main()

  File "C:/Users/Shah family/Desktop/Coding/python/encrypted code.py", line 40, in main
    main()

  File "C:/Users/Shah family/Desktop/Coding/python/encrypted code.py", line 40, in main
    main()

 [Previous line repeated 989 more times]

 File "C:/Users/Shah family/Desktop/Coding/python/encrypted code.py", line 35, in main
    if user_sentance[counter_1] == alphabet[counter_2]:

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

WHAT SHOULD I DO???

Comment: You should stop calling `main()` from `main()`.

Comment: you dont have a stopping/breaking condition for the recursive function you use.

Comment: You should: remove all the commented out code; remove the pointless `counter_1` and `counter_2` functions; not call `main()` from `main()` without a decent stop condition for this recursion - or probably better, put the recursion in a well-defined recursive function and call that once from `main()`.

Comment: What is the program *supposed* to do?  If we don't know your desired result, including whether you mean to use recursion, we can't recommend a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a condition to end the loop. `main()` on line 38 keeps getting called and the program is stopped because it's in an infinite loop.

What you should do, fix your if statement to have a condition to end or break the loop, like a bool value, or return, or check the comment on this post.

Also calling the main function recursively is never a good idea, thats what making other functions are for.

Comment: Adding `wait` or `exit` calls just exacerbates an already bad solution - a recursive function can simply return an appropriate value (or `None` if that's appropriate) when it's stop condition is reached.

Comment: I agree with that statement. I was trying to just point out that there should be a condition to end the program when I should have said loop. You're right though, the function should return something even if its nothing.